# Mathematical logic

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

Given:

1. $[(A \lor B) \land (A \lor C)] \rightarrow [A \lor (B \land C)]$;
2. $\lnot((x_1 < x_2) \rightarrow (x_1 \cdot x_3 > x_2 \cdot x_3))$
3. $\forall x_2:f_1^2(x_2, x_3) \rightarrow P_1^2(f_1^1(x_1), f_1^3(x_1, a_2, x_1))$;

The tasks are:

Q1. To derive (1) in the propositional calculus.

Q2. To give examples of 3 interpretations: Tautology, Contradiction, Satisfiable (but not tautological) of (2).

Q3. Is (3) a formula?

---

[image]![]

Comment: If you post a picture of the statements you're working on, please at *least* orient it horizontally.

Comment: What progress have you made so far?

Comment: I've solved the first one)

Comment: In (3), what's the first symbol? Looks like '7'.

Comment: It's negation(complement).

Comment: I don't know what 2 means.  Which has precedence $\lor$ or &?  Does A $\lor$ B & C mean [( A $\lor$ B)& C] or [A $\lor$ (B & C)]?  What are the axioms and rules of inference of your system?

Comment: @DougSpoonwood & has over v, and v has over $\rightarrow$

Comment: I guess there's a mistake in 2 and A ∨ B & C means [A ∨ (B & C)], but I've already solved that problem :)

Comment: It's been said that "ask 7 different engineers to draw an arrow, and you'll get 7 different arrows."  However, "$\supset$" means super set; it is very well defined and accepted.  If you mean implication, please use an arrow $\rightarrow$.  If you insist on using an alternative symbol, the Iverson Bracket dual to implication is less than $\le$.  The set dual to $\le$ is $\subseteq$.  $\supset$ would suggest exactly the opposite of implication.

Comment: @DanielV: but $\supset$ is indeed a very well established symbol for implication. It has nothing to do with superset; it comes from a "C" rotated 180 degrees, which dates all the way back to Peano.

Answer (score 2):

Question 3) : **NO**, it is not a *well-formed* formula.

$f_1^2$ is a *function symbol (the first in the enumeration of bynary ones) : it take as "input" a *term* (variable or constant) an gives as "output" another *term* (i.e. a "name").

Thus, $f_1^1(x_2,x_3)$ is a *term* and **not** a *formula* and the syntax of the connective "$\rightarrow$" is :

> $A \rightarrow B$,

where $A$ and $B$ must be formulas.

About Question 2) : it is not clear to me how to interpret the statement of the problem.

The formula :

> $\lnot ((x_1 < x_2) \rightarrow (x_1⋅x_3 > x_2⋅x_3))$

is clearly *satisfiable*; let $x_1 := 1$, $x_2 := 2$ and $x_3 := 3$, then :

$(1 < 2) \rightarrow (1.3 > 2.3)$ i.e. $(1 < 2) \rightarrow (3 > 6)$

is *false*; thus its negation : $\lnot [(1 < 2) \rightarrow (3 > 6)]$ is *true*.

In conclusion, having found an *interpretation* with *domain* the set $\mathbb N$ of natural numbers where the formula is true, it is *satisfiable*.

But about *tautology* ? A *tautology* (or *valid* formula) is a formula which is true in *all* interpretations; but the formula is basically :

> $\lnot (p \rightarrow q)$

and this is not a tautology (and neither a contradiction). Furthermore, a *contradiction* is a formula which is *false* for every interpretation; thus, what is the meaning of :

> find an "examples of [an] interpretations [such that the formula is a] contradiction" ?

We have found and interpretation (in $\mathbb N$) of the formula which satisfy it; thus, being true in at least one interpretation, the formula obviously is **not** a contradiction.